# How to include plugins into a SNAP for a QT5 desktop app?

Tags: plugins, qt5, snapcraft

I have got a desktop application for Linux written with QT5 and I want to deploy it as a SNAP package.
The build and install works but the app is not executable and gives the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

Here is my snapcraft.yaml

```
name: animationmaker
version: '1.0'
summary: Create keyframe animation and export them to a movie file
description: |
  This app can be used to create animated movie based on keyframe animations.

grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  animationmaker:
    command: AnimationMaker

parts:
  animationmaker:
    plugin: qmake
    qt-version: qt5
    source: https://github.com/Artanidos/AnimationMaker.git
```

I think the plugins from QT5 are missing but I don't know how to alter the yaml to include them.
When I builded an AppImage there were the following plugins included iconengines, imageformats and platform.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are included in `libqt5gui5`, which you can add as a stage package like so:

```
parts:
  animationmaker:
    plugin: qmake
    qt-version: qt5
    source: https://github.com/Artanidos/AnimationMaker.git
    stage-packages: [libqt5gui5]
```

However, Snapcraft supports remote parts, one of which is an excellent desktop Qt helper that pull this type of thing in for you and sets a common environment, etc. It's pretty well documented [in this tutorial](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/11/17/how-to-create-snap-packages-on-qt-applications/), but for completeness, try this:

```
parts:
  animationmaker:
    plugin: qmake
    qt-version: qt5
    source: https://github.com/Artanidos/AnimationMaker.git
    after: [desktop-qt5]
```

And make your app use the `desktop-launch` helper:

```
apps:
  animationmaker:
    command: desktop-launch AnimationMaker
```

Comment: Thx, but first solution did not help and the second solution give the following error message:
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't even get your `snapcraft.yaml` to build (you're missing many `build-packages`), so I can't help you debug that much. You remembered to use the `desktop-launch` wrapper as well?

Comment: Yes, I used the launcher. What build-packages are missing?

Comment: Several libav packages, but even once I had all those it just didn't build.

Comment: Yes,I am using ffmpeg but I do not know how to put them into the snapcraft.yaml if its the right place at all.

Comment: @Kyle your tutorial link is a 404

Comment: Thanks @Ads2000. Fixed.